# Free memory of array in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, memory, record, pascal

While using FastMM4, there have been memory leaks by system.pas in the function DynArraySetLength. I am using a list where each element has 5 records. These records are in turn list of order of several million. Hence the small memory leaks accumulate to be huge chunk.

While freeing up the element, I am deliberately using SetLength(x,0) and x:=nil.
But still, there is a memory leak in DynArraySetLength of system.pas.
Can someone suggest me how to free up the array using an efficient way and get across this memory leak.

Thanks in advance

CODE:
The memory leak occurs at SetLength of this procedure

```
 procedure TElem.Assign(Value: TElem);
 begin
 SetLength(Self.aXY.points, Length(Value.aXY.points)); //MEMORY LEAK
 Move(Value.aXY.points[0], Self.aXY.points[0],
 Length(Value.aXY.points) * SizeOf(coordinate));
 end;
```

While freeing I am using this procedure:

```
 procedure TElem.FreeElem;
 begin
 SetLength(Self.aXY.points,0);
 Self.aXY.points:=nil;
 end;
```

Comment: Where is `x` declaration and other relevant code?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without the actual code.

Comment: The memory leak occurs at SetLength of this procedure TElem.Assign(Value: TElem);
begin
  SetLength(Self.aXY.points, Length(Value.aXY.points));
  Move(Value.aXY.points[0], Self.aXY.points[0],
    Length(Value.aXY.points) * SizeOf(coordinate));
end;
While freeing I am using this procedure:
procedure TElem.FreeElem;
begin
  SetLength(Self.aXY.points,0);
  Self.aXY.points:=nil;
end;

Comment: Edit your question. Don't forget declarations

Comment: `Move` is low-level procedure. It doesn't treat  properly managed types in array elements... But we still know nothing about elements.

Comment: Please add declarations that others alrady asked for, and also explain how you know there is a memory leak and what's the size of the leak after just one array allocation/deallocation?

Comment: What @MBo correctly states is that if you fool the system by using a low level routine like `Move`, then any reference counting doesn't work properly and you get problems. Don't do that.

Answer (score 10):

Dynamic arrays are managed and so freed automatically by the system when their scope ends. So you don't actually need to free them explicitly. Of course, if you do wish to release them before their scope ends, you can do so. It suffices to do:

```
SetLength(aXY.points, 0);
```

or

```
aXY.points := nil;
```

or

```
Finalize(aXY.points);
```

Each of these three statements are identical. You can pick one of them, but there's no point doing more than one. For instance, this suffices:

```
procedure TElem.FreeElem;
begin
  aXY.points := nil;
end;
```

---

None of this explains why you have a leak. As I explained, dynamic arrays are managed, and so when their scope ends, they will be destroyed.

The obvious conclusion to this is that the scope of the dynamic array never ends. That would happen if your code leaked `TElem` instances. If you fail to destroy the `TElem` instances that own the array, then the arrays themselves will not be destroyed, and will leak.

Another cause for a leak could be that the elements of the array are managed types themselves. `Move` performs a "blind" memory copy and bypasses the lifetime management of any managed types in the array. If your array elements have managed types (strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces, etc.) then using `Move` is a mistake.

Comment: If I had to guess, I think it most likely that you aren't destroying the `TElem` instances. Don't make us guess. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: FWIW, info for @alphasin: instead of `SetLength(A, Length(B)); Move(B[0], A[0], SizeOf()...);`, it is much easier and perfectly safe to do: `A := Copy(B);`. That also works properly for managed types. If the values are not modified, even a simple `A := B;` will do.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I think it is very likely that in a method named `TElem.Assign` a copy is the elements is required.

Comment: yes, indeed. What do you think Copy(dynarray) does? Or did you mean plain assignment? If COW is implemented (in the class, not for dynarrays), a copy may not be required (at that time). A mere assignment of the dynaray references may be enough.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis My point is that it is pretty unlikely that `A := B` will be appropriate in a method named `Assign`.

Comment: Why? It probably does an assignment. Depending on how the dynarray is used, `A := B;` may be enough.

Comment: @Rudy The `Assign` method usually has to perform a deep copy rather than a shallow copy. Otherwise you can write `Elem1.Assigned(Elem2)` and then make changes to `Elem2` that show up in `Elem1`.

Comment: I already said: "if the values are not modified". Of course he or she must make a copy if the values are modified. I wrote that already.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well, that's the entire point of `Assign` isn't it. Have you ever seen an `Assign` method in the RTL or VCL that doesn't do a deep copy?

Comment: It depends on how "deep". It usually only copies the relevant members. Whether that means copying the elements of a dynarray or not depends on what the class is supposed to do. Sometimes it copies class references, sometimes it copies their contents too. Sometimes it copies dynarrays, sometimes it copies the elements too. Again: depends on the needs.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Nope, it's almost always a deep copy.